# How to separate a list of serial numbers into multiple lists with matched prefix?

Tags: python

I have Three patterned serial numbers in a list as below example:

> sn = [bike-001, bike-002, car/001, bus/for/001, car/002, bus/for/002]

I want to separate them in to multiple lists as below example:

> sn1 = [bike-001, bike-002]
>
> sn2 = [car/001, car/002]
>
> sn3 = [bus/for/001, bus/for/002]

The numbers only will be changed every time. How to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings have `.startswith(<sub_str>)` method which will help you here. You can use list comprehension with a simple check to get desired output:

```
sn = ['bike-001', 'bike-002', 'car/001', 'bus/for/001', 'car/002', 'bus/for/002']

sn_1 = [i for i in sn if i.startswith('bike')]
sn_2 = [i for i in sn if i.startswith('car')]
sn_3 = [i for i in sn if i.startswith('bus')]
```

Result would look like this:

```
['bike-001', 'bike-002']
['car/001', 'car/002']
['bus/for/001', 'bus/for/002']
```